# How to install Lubuntu core?

Tags: lubuntu

I am a very beginner in Linux...
I use Lubuntu Desktop..

Tell me please how to make a new fresh install of Lubuntu core?

I can't find Lubuntu core's iso file, and I can't find the direct download link for mini.iso...

Thank you.

Comment: I think you may be refering to Xubuntu core http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/05/xubuntu-core-new-minimal-iso-download

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lubuntu-core

Comment: Not sure why you couldn't find it, [here it is](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall) with all the mini.iso links, etc. Note, there has never been a lubuntu core iso. In case you still can't find the direct link, here is [the 14.04 mini.iso 32bit](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso).

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever. Can someone tell me please how to find out if now I am using Lubuntu Core/Desktop please?

Comment: Try `dpkg -l | grep lubuntu-core` to check if the package is installed. I am not quite sure of your idea of using it. Having it installed is pretty much all there is.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep lubuntu-core
ii  lubuntu-core                                0.55                                    i386         Lubuntu Desktop environment - minimal installation`
It seems I am using Lubuntu Core?

Comment: Well, happy for you! ...problem solved?

Comment: @mikewhatever but... "lubuntu-desktop needs lubuntu-core in order work, so it makes sense you would already be using it, or have it." ? :) So I still could using Lubuntu Desktop now?

Comment: Sure, what's wrong with using both?

Comment: @mikewhatever I am interested to use an as simpler, slimmer, faster, lightware OS as possible... Still someone please help me to find out if I use Lubuntu Core/Desktop? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24794/discussion-between-xpdin-and-mikewhatever).

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall). As @mikewhatever says there are no Lubuntu Core ISOs. Instead, the directions specify downloading an Ubuntu minimal ISO. It appears that the installer menu may offer you the option to do a Lubuntu Core installation, but if not, you can run the following from a terminal window after the installation is complete:

```
sudo -i
apt-get install lubuntu-core
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoclean
rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
reboot
```

Instead of installing Lubuntu Core you can also keep your current Lubuntu Desktop install and uninstall packages you don't want using Synaptic or [one of the other tools provided with Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Setup).

New Windows machines tend to use something called UEFI when booting which [the minimal install ISOs don't support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD):

> While the minimal iso image is handy, it isn't useful for installing
>   on UEFI-based systems that you want to run in UEFI mode. The mini iso
>   lacks the proper files for booting the computer in UEFI mode. Thus,
>   the computer will boot in BIOS compatibility mode, and the
>   installation will be in BIOS mode.

So I would say there's some extra potential to run into headaches, especially if you're dual-booting with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help someone...

```
aptitude
--- Installed Packages (1279)
--- Not installed Packages (44436)
--- Virtual Packages (5049)
--- Tasks (24509)

These packages are currently installed on your computer

This group contains 1279 packages.
```

A great Sunday to all ! :)

Comment: ubuntu:22.04  how to install  Lubuntu Desktop core?